# Get Ipv6 Full Format In Java

Tags: java, ipv6

I have an ipv6 like:**"2001:cdba::3257:9652".** I want get ipv6 in full format like: **2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652**. Does has any function in java to do that? And how to compress a ipv6 full format?
Thanks all.

Comment: Use the java.net.Inet6Address Class:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think it will return "2001:cdba:0:0:0:0:3257:9652" but I need fully "2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652"

Comment: Actually, I wrote a function to do that but I want to know: Does has any function in java to do that?

Comment: [RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952) has an affect on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method in the standard Java libraries to do that.

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) has methods to produce those formats and various other string formats.

Here is a code sample:

```
    IPAddressString addrString = new IPAddressString("2001:cdba::3257:9652");
    IPAddress addr = addrString.getAddress();
    String string = addr.toFullString();
    System.out.println(string);
    string = addr.toCanonicalString();
    System.out.println(string);
```

The output is:

```
2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652
2001:cdba::3257:9652
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import com.google.common.net.InetAddresses;
// Convert the short IPv6 address to a full version
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddresses.forString(shortIPv6); 
return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation or rationale here?